# How to reference a paper and also mention the year it was published for the first time?

Tags: biblatex

I want to cite the paper "Der barycentrische Calcul" by A. F. Möbius. Now it was first published in 1827, but the text I'm going to cite is in his "Gesammelte Werke", that is, "collected works", which has been published in 1885. How can I make it so that it is cited as "Möbius (1827)", and not "Möbius (1885)", but without falsely writing

```
year = 1885
```

?

Right now, I use @incollection for papers in books or collected papers, and also tried @inbook. Which is the appropriate one, and is what I want even achievable?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would work with `@inbook` and the field `crossref`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reference.bib}
@book{moebius1885,
      author = {A. F. Möbius},
      title = {Gesammelte Werke},
      year = {1885},
    }
@inbook{moebius1827,
      author = {A. F. Möbius},
      title = {Der barycentrische Calcul},
      year = {1827},
     crossref={moebius1885}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{moebius1885}

\cite{moebius1827}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you @Marco! I didn't know about the crossref field.